# create_search_index fails with Motor/PyMongo on MongoDB 6.0.14 (on Atlas free tier)

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a vector search index. My MongoDB is 6.0.14 (latest currently deployed in Atlas free tier). vector search and indices have been back ported to the latest 6.0.x in addition to 7.x. I can create a search index using the Atlas web interface. I cannot using the APIs (through Motor/PyMongo). It fails with `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command not found, full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'command not found', 'code': 59, 'codeName': 'CommandNotFound'}`

In `pymongo/collection.py`:

```
    def create_search_indexes(
        self,
        models: list[SearchIndexModel],
        session: Optional[ClientSession] = None,
        comment: Optional[Any] = None,
        **kwargs: Any,
    ) -> list[str]:
        ...
        with self._conn_for_writes(session) as conn:
            resp = self._command(   # ERROR HERE
```

I expected this to work on versions that have that functionality. Which means both 7.x and the newer 6.0.14. Is there a way to make this work? Is this a bug in PyMongo 4.6.1?